# slack still uninstalls overnight

Tags: upgrade, dpkg, uninstall, 21.04, slack

The Slack client suddenly started uninstalling overnight (Linux 21.10 OS
as installed) on my laptop and the remedy was to reinstall using 'dpkg'.

I'd been wanting to upgrade to a supported OS so upgraded to 21.04 thinking
there was nothing to lose and that in itself might fix the slack issue:

That seems to indicate to me that 'dpkg' is doing the delete.
So what runs 'dpkg' during the night, not a cronjob that I can identify?

I'm having to reinstall Slack each morning.

Any ideas what may be causing the uninstall overnight?

Comment: If you reboot your machine right now, is Slack uninstalled? Or does it really only happen in the dark of the night while you are away from the system?

Comment: Can you take a look at the dpkg logs to find out exactly when that is happening ? or is it even happening because of dpkg like you said ? The dpkg log is present in `/var/log/dpkg.log` in my system atleast. It can be that for some reason, you might be installing them on a temporary drive, which clears out overnight for some reason. ?